# Windows 10 / JS : I am stuck with debugging "HelloWorld" app

Tags: javascript, html, visual-studio, windows-10

I have some experience on HTML5 & JS but really a novice with Windows 10 UWP. At first, I tried to implement simple HelloWorld with HTML5/JS/Win 10/Visual Studio following the instructions of:
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/mt280216.aspx

I got the application working without problems but when I tried to study the control flow of the app, I faced some problems:

- console.log("text") does not seem to output anything into Visual Studio JavaScript console window. How should I do logging in Windows 10 / Visual studio?
- when running my HelloWorld in Visual Studio "localMachine", breakpoints are not working; only when I am running HelloWorld in Visual Studio Emulator, the breakpoints work. What I am doing wrong?

Visual studio is quite complex piece of a tool, so probably I am missing some settings somewhere, so could somebody explain what I am doing wrong

Comment: while debugging, do `System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(message: "Test", category: "MyApp");`, it will write to your output window. (to view, ensure your combobox has `Debug` selected in that window.. which it should be default if you're running in debug)...

Comment: In my understanding, System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine is supported in C#/C++/F#/VB but not JS

Comment: Is seems that the problem is VS2015 error "Application is not currently attached to a script debug target that supports script diagnostics". I created new question  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33464495/vs2015-error-application-is-not-currently-attached-to-a-script-debug-target-tha